# Use readonly IMemoryCache in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

I'm using IMemoryCache in my .Net Core application. This is how I write/read something to the cache:

```
List<Track> tracks = null;

if (!_cache.TryGetValue("tracks", out tracks) {

tracks = DbSelect.getAllTracks(groupId, "tracks", true);

var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
       .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(3))
       .SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10));

_cache.Set("tracks", tracks, cacheEntryOptions);

}
```

In some cases I need to add or remove some objects to 'tracks'. This is user based. It should not be the case that if user x adds an object to 'tracks', user y sees this addition in 'tracks'. The basic dataset is the same for every user, but for certain cases I need to extend 'tracks' or remove certain objects.

When I manipulate 'tracks', the cache is also manipulated. Is there a way to make the cache readonly?

I know I can serialize/deserialize 'tracks' to cut the link to the cache, but the cost is too great: 'tracks' is a huge object and it takes too long to serialize/deserialize every time I run a manipulation on 'tracks'...

Comment: Where is your IMemoryCache created, and what type is it? Are you getting it through dependency injection? If so, is it a singleton?

Comment: The cache always stores a reference to an object, so you have to make a copy.

Comment: Use a `ImmutableList<Track>` as the thing you store in the cache. Then the user tracks can be made from that base list. When you add or remove items it makes a new instance and the original is unmodifed.